# Class not found error laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I trying to create this [application](http://www.kodeinfo.com/post/referral-tree-using-jorgchart-and-laravel-php) and I got Class 'App\Http\Controllers\KodeInfo\jorgchart' not found error in Homecontroller.php ... What I was wrong on here? and at end of article i didn't catch the instruction : "At last autoload the KodeInfo directory so our new class will work" - I mean how to autoload the directory !

PS:: I already added namespace App\Http\Controllers; to the top of Homecontroller and yeah already composer dump autoload also

Any idea?

Comment: can i know what u trying to route ?? menz what is the url u getting this error?

Comment: How have you included it in your Controller? i.e your `use` statement for it.

Comment: thanks guys for replying , but the issue was resolved .. but anyways Thank you @HamelRaj  and thanks for the help man for sharing the code.

Comment: hey thanks man for the help !! @James

Answer (score 0):

in your **HomeController** head use this

```
use App\KodeInfo\jorgchart;
```

or

```
$jorg = new App\KodeInfo\JOrgChart();
```